# how can some apps be small in size even though having lots of images?

Tags: android, image, android-support-library

I have an android app which is 35 MB in size. I am using around 50 images in that app because of that scrolling is not smooth and sometimes app crashes with errors like out of memory, whereas there are other apps which are using 100 images but are smaller in size, like 2 MB or so and these app work offline also.
I want to ask why these apps are small in size? are they using any library?

Comment: There are plenty of reasons. First is the size of your assets. If your app is laggy it could be because your images are too heavy. What are the size, weight, type (png, jpg, ...) of the images you're using?

Comment: How large an image is depends on the used format, the size, the image content (-> compressibility) and the used compression options. On android side I doubt that there is something special.

Comment: someone suggested me to use glide for loading and caching images. will it work offline if i use glide library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it may work for you

convert all your jpeg ,png,etc etc images into " webp" it may take less space and 
same quality of your picture...

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/convert-webp.html#convert_images_to_webp

Don't store all images in drawable rather make  small json file and fetch all the data from your app so you can get a apk with smaller size and fast

some code is also their how to get data from offline also..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1) **Reduce Images size from this website.**

[Tiny PNG](https://tinypng.com)

> TinyPNG uses smart lossy compression techniques to reduce the file
>   size of your PNG files

2) **Put images in different drawable folder**.

Using this website to generate different drawable:

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html

3) **Use SVG or 9 patch if it is possible**.

Comment: I have already tried it except the third option. what if i use 100 images and the app should work offline also?